# Controling the order on wordpress contribution pages

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

I have a contribution page for membership signup, dues and other member information. It is a "on behalf of an organization" style membership. Right now, the form displays the fields in this order

1. membership pricelist
2. "on behalf of organization" details
3. wordpress account creation
4. and 5 - 2 other profiles I've added using the "Profiles" capacity of contribution forms.

Is there a way to have the order instead be 4, 5, 3, 2, 1? Should this be done through CSS or is there a better way? The "order" field doesn't seem to do much in this regards.

Answer (score 2):

There is no UI enabled way to control the order. You'll need to do some of the above via a custom template.

The profiles have a top / bottom ordering which might help a wee bit. More info on customizing templates here:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Customize+Built-in,+Profile,+Contribution+and+Event+Registration+Screens